# Total number of working hours

Tags: sql

I got this table:

```
CardID      | timein                    |   timeout 
-------------------------------------------------------
4946        |8/11/2017 2:00:00 PM       |   8/11/2017 3:30:00 PM
6422        |8/5/2017  1:15:00 PM       |   8/5/2017 2:45:00 PM 
6422        |8/12/2017 1:15:00 PM       |   8/12/2017 2:45:00 PM
6538        |8/7/2017  5:30:00 PM       |   8/7/2017 8:30:00 PM
6538        |8/4/2017  8:00:00 AM       |   8/4/2017 11:00:00 AM    
6538        |8/3/2017  5:30:00 PM       |   8/3/2017 8:30:00 PM 
7442        |8/10/2017 9:00:00 AM       |   8/10/2017 12:00:00 PM   
7442        |8/8/2017  4:00:00 PM       |   8/8/2017 7:00:00 PM 
7442        |8/1/2017  10:00:00 AM      |   8/1/2017 1:00:00 PM 
7442        |8/3/2017  9:00:00 AM       |   8/3/2017 12:00:00 PM    
7442        |8/1/2017  4:00:00 PM       |   8/1/2017 7:00:00 PM 
7442        |8/2/2017  4:00:00 PM       |   8/2/2017 7:00:00 PM 
7442        |8/15/2017 4:00:00 PM       |   8/15/2017 7:00:00 PM    
7442        |8/9/2017  4:00:00 PM       |   8/9/2017 7:00:00 PM 
7442        |8/1/2017  10:00:00 AM      |   8/1/2017 1:00:00 PM 
9330        |8/9/2017  4:00:00 PM       |   8/9/2017 7:00:00 PM 
9330        |8/1/2017  10:00:00 AM      |   8/1/2017 1:00:00 PM
```

I was able to get the total of time per row per each person. However, I want to get the grand total of hour per month. Example: cardID 7442 has checked in for 5 days. I want to total hours of these 5 days.

Comment: Since you already "get the total time per row per each person", you can SUM it up and GROUP BY each cardID.

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  CardID,
  DATEPART(mm, timein),
  SUM(DATEPART(hh, timeout - timein))
FROM tempdb..workhours
GROUP BY CardID,
         DATEPART(mm, timeout)
```

This will give you the total by `CardID` per month. Remove `DATEPART(mm, timein)` if you don't care for the specific month.